# Sometimes I am getting error “unexpected end of stream on connection” while calling web service from android

Tags: android, mysql, rest, web-services

Sometimes I am getting error “unexpected end of stream on connection” while calling web service from android using go daddy server and hosting.

In pick hours my application got [this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfm0Y.jpg)

**AppController.class**

```
private void initRetrofitConfig() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Connection", "close").build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            })
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(SERVICE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    apiEndpoint = retrofit.create(ApiEndpoint.class);
}

public ApiEndpoint getApiEndpoint() {
    if (apiEndpoint == null) {
        initRetrofitConfig();
    }
    return apiEndpoint;
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838774/java-io-ioexception-unexpected-end-of-stream-on-connection-in-android